# How to transfer compressed gas GH2 from one tank to another at the same pressure?

Tags: process-engineering, standards, compressed-gases, energy-storage, equipment-selection

The problem is to transfer all the compressed hydrogen from one tank on a ship at 400 bars to fill another tank on earth (also to fill it at 400 bars). What are the common technologies and equipment (compressor, valves, connections)?

Answer (score 0):

Pump a fluid in the target tank into the source tank, use a fluid that is inert and will not mix with the hydrogen.

Answer (score 0):

A pressure differential of some sort is required to move fluids.

The common usage for these things is pumps, often called compressors for gasses, and pipes.  Pressures of gasses change as you add or subtract from the container they are in.  That makes this a non-trivial exercise, as eventually the ship's container would be at a vacuum, requiring a vacuum pump, and a very expensive one if you truly mean "all."  If the ship's container can be modified, a bladder might be an option.

The tech for Compressed Natural Gas haulers might be of interest.  It seems unlikely that the expense for such a high pressure installation would make sense on land.  High pressures for transport can pay out but I doubt if you would store it on land at such pressures, plus you want to store it at lower pressure so you can get some of the cost of pressurization back.

Answer (score 0):

There is a relatively simple device called a gas booster that can be run on compressed air, which may serve this purpose. No electrical power is needed, which may be advantageous to avoid ignition risks with hydrogen.